# Repeating SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running same query for different values. Such as I am querying the table for aa, bb, cc, dd, ee ... Is there any way like as function and use parameters rather than duplication my codes 10 times only for one variable changes.
I am pretty new, and don't know what to name of my solution. I do appreciate any ideas, or let me know if you need more details. 
I am using toad for oracle, and need oracle sql solution.

Comment: How about writing a *single* query with *all* variables?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF need to function you can use below sample :

```
FUNCTION GET_values( Any arguments to that query)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS 
BEGIN
        SELECT value
          INTO v_value
          FROM table
         WHERE condition;
    RETURN v_value;
END GET_values;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple query like this

```
select * from table where value in ('aa','bb','cc','dd','ee')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cursor for the solution.

```
declare 
cursor c1(value1 varchar) is
select columns from tab1
where column1= value1;
l_columns varchar2;
begin

OPEN c1(aa);
fetch c1 into l_columns ;
close c1;


end;
```